# Returning data from single Google Sheets row from .gs file to .js file

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a web app in Google scripts that returns project data based on a search query. I have the search query functioning correctly, however, the returned array `filteredRows` has a length of 1 when I query it, therefore when I try to use the values based on index, they are still all together. There are 12 columns in the spreadsheet. The function is returning the correct information back to me js file though.

I have tried `JSON.stringify` and I couldn't get it to work, but it is not something I have used before. I do suspect the answer lies there though.

The spreadsheet may have hundreds of lines, but I only want to return one at a time for manipulation.

Here is the code for the search function. `var headers` and `var cols` are there from trying to use the JSON method, but otherwise not doing anything right now.

```
function searchProject(tendNumber) {

   var id = 'mySpreadSheetId';
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
   PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("tend", tendNumber);
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName('Data');
   var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(), 12).getValues();
   var headers = data[0];
   var cols = headers.length;
   Logger.log(headers);
   var filteredRows = data.filter(function(row){
   var ids = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("tend");
    if (row[4] == ids){
      return row;
   }

})

 return (filteredRows);
}
```

Any guidance as to which direction to go would be greatly appreciated. There does seem to be a lot of info available, but I need a pointer to fully understand it.

I have edited this in case it helps others. The answer was actually simple.

As stated all was working but I couldn’t access the indexes in the array. I wasn’t aware that it actually returns an Array of Arrays, therefore if I access array[0] it will return all of the first inner array.

To access each individual element of the returned row or rows it is array[0][0].

Answer (score 1):

`var filteredRows = data.filter(function(row){
   var ids = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("tend");
    if (row[4] == ids){
      return row;
   }`

You don't really want to return the row you just want to return a truthy

`var ids = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("tend");
 data.filter(function(row){return row[4] == ids;}`

Your don't really want to declare ids inside the loop either since it's going to be the same for the whole function as it's a function parameter.

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

The filter() method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function. i.e. that return true

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the feedback. I have a question on the variable. the `tendNumber` is passed to the `searchProject` function from the .js file. The only reason I have declared `ids` is because I couldn't use `tendNumber` inside a second function. where should I declare `ids` as when I tried it I couldn't use it inside `data.filter(function(row){return row[4] == ids;}` as it's inside another function. I know I am missing something!

Comment: if you declared with a var there should have been no problem.  I take a look at a simple example to see if I misunderstand something.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I managed to sole the issue as stated in the edited question